# Regex for pattern with prefix

Tags: regex

I want to write regex for any of the below pattern

```
  1140×90.0
  軸距C(M/T)[648(534+114)×90.0]
  軸距E[643(529+114)×90.0]
  軸距E(M/T)[768(654+114)×90.0]enter code here
   軸距G[1098(984+114)×90.0]
    軸距G(M/T)[1223(1109+114)×90.0]
```

I am using

```
\[*\d*(\d\.[\d]+)?(\(\d+(\.[\d]+)?\+\d*([\d]*\d\.[\d]+)?\))?\×\d+([\d]*\.[\d]+)?\]*
```

It is working for below patters:

```
    [648(534+114)×90.0]
    [643(529+114)×90.0]
    [768(654+114)×90.0]
    1098(984+114)×90.0]
    [1223(1109+114)×90.0]
    890×90.0
```

Now I want to prefix above any of words before above patterns

```
    1140×90.0
    軸距C(M/T)[648(534+114)×90.0]
    軸距E[643(529+114)×90.0]
    軸距E(M/T)[768(654+114)×90.0]
    軸距G[1098(984+114)×90.0]`enter code here`
    軸距G(M/T)[1223(1109+114)×90.0]
```

Please let me know how to do this

Comment: You already have the right match correct? Can you replace using the full match prepended with your replacement string? Should the string `enter code here` be there, or  did that happen when creating the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[^\s\[\]]*\[*\d*\.?\d+(?:\(\d*\.?\d+\+\d*\.?\d+\))?×(?:\d*\.?\d+)?\]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tKaRai/2).

*Details*:

- `[^\s\[\]]*` - zero or more chars other than square brackets and whitespace
- `\[*` - zero or more `[` chars
- `\d*\.?\d+` - an int/float number
- `(?:\(\d*\.?\d+\+\d*\.?\d+\))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `\d*\.?\d+` - an int or float number
  - `\+` -  a `+` char
  - `\d*\.?\d+` -  an int or float number
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `×` - a `×` char
- `(?:\d*\.?\d+)?` - an optional sequence matching an int/float number
- `\]*` - zero or more `]` chars.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need the capture groups, but you can prepend the pattern with a non greedy dot `.*?` to match all before the pattern  until you encounter the pattern.

```
.*?\d+(\.\d+)?(\(\d+(\.\d+)?\+\d+(\.\d+)?\))?×\d+(\.\d+)?\]*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MXWWzL/1)

Or match for example optionally any kind of letter followed by an optional part between parenthesis:

```
(?:\p{L}+(?:\([^()]*\))?)?\[?\d+(\.\d+)?(\(\d+(\.\d+)?\+\d+(\.\d+)?\))?×\d+(\.\d+)?\]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LKlxIc/1)